How can i parse GT06N Protocol Data from HEX to Text
i have been working on receiving data from a GPS tracker using the GT06N Protocol and i have managed to successfully receive the packets but now my problem is extracting the data out from the packets, i have been following the GT06N protocol documentation but i am hitting dead ends, so what i need help with is to extract the data from the Packet, thats where am stuck.
Here is My Current Code
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import zlib
import os


os.environ['TZ'] = 'Africa/Nairobi'

# Function to calculate CRC-ITU (CRC-16-CCITT-FALSE) error check
def crc_itu(data):
    crc = 0xFFFF
    polynomial = 0x1021

    for byte in data:
        crc ^= (byte << 8)

        for _ in range(8):
            if crc & 0x8000:
                crc = ((crc << 1) ^ polynomial) & 0xFFFF
            else:
                crc = (crc << 1) & 0xFFFF

    return crc.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')

# Set timezone to Africa/Nairobi


# Create a TCP server socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((my_server_ip, my_server_port))
server.listen(1)

print("Waiting for connection...")

# Accept a client connection
socket, _ = server.accept()

print("Connection established.")

# Receive data from the client
encoded_data = socket.recv(1500)

# Extracting the Information Serial Number
serial_number_hex = binascii.hexlify(encoded_data)[-10:-6]
new_serial_number_hex = hex(int(serial_number_hex, 16) + 1)[2:].zfill(4)

# Calculating the error check (CRC-ITU)
error_check_data = binascii.hexlify(encoded_data)[4:-10]
error_check = crc_itu(binascii.unhexlify(error_check_data))

# Constructing the server's response packet
server_response_packet = b"78780501" + bytes.fromhex(new_serial_number_hex) + error_check + b"0D0A"

TrackerData = binascii.hexlify(encoded_data).decode()

print("Received: ", TrackerData)
print("Server Reply: ", server_response_packet.hex().upper())

# Send the server's response packet to the client
socket.sendall(server_response_packet)


def convert_to_decimal(hex_bytes):
    return int.from_bytes(hex_bytes, byteorder='big')

def parse_datetime(datetime_bytes):
    year = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[0:1]) + 2000
    month = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[1:2])
    day = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[2:3])
    hour = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[3:4])
    minute = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[4:5])
    second = convert_to_decimal(datetime_bytes[5:6])
    return f"{year}-{month}-{day} {hour}:{minute}:{second}"

def parse_latitude(latitude_bytes):
    latitude_decimal = convert_to_decimal(latitude_bytes)
    latitude_decimal /= 30000 * 60
    return latitude_decimal

def parse_longitude(longitude_bytes):
    longitude_decimal = convert_to_decimal(longitude_bytes)
    longitude_decimal /= 30000 * 60
    return longitude_decimal

def parse_speed(speed_byte):
    return convert_to_decimal(speed_byte)

def parse_course(course_bytes):
    return convert_to_decimal(course_bytes)

packet = TrackerData

start_bit = packet[0:4]
packet_length = packet[4:6]
protocol_no = packet[6:8]
date_time = parse_datetime(bytes.fromhex(packet[8:20]))
quantity_gps_info_satellites = packet[20:22]
latitude = parse_latitude(bytes.fromhex(packet[22:30]))
longitude = parse_longitude(bytes.fromhex(packet[30:38]))
speed = parse_speed(bytes.fromhex(packet[38:40]))
course = parse_course(bytes.fromhex(packet[40:44]))
mcc = packet[44:48]
mnc = packet[48:50]
lac = packet[50:54]
cell_id = packet[54:60]
serial_no = packet[60:64]
error_check = packet[64:68]
stop_bit = packet[68:72]

print("Start Bit:", start_bit)
print("Packet Length:", packet_length)
print("Protocol No:", protocol_no)
print("Date Time:", date_time)
print("Quantity of GPS Information Satellites:", quantity_gps_info_satellites)
print("Latitude:", latitude)
print("Longitude:", longitude)
print("Speed:", speed, "km/h")
print("Course:", course, "degrees")
print("MCC:", mcc)
print("MNC:", mnc)
print("LAC:", lac)
print("Cell ID:", cell_id)
print("Serial No:", serial_no)
print("Error Check:", error_check)
print("Stop Bit:", stop_bit)




# Close the connection
socket.close()
server.close()

Here is what i get

starting with the date its self its very wrong we are in 2024 its showing 2008
Here is a sample Packet
**78780d010865784052326215000516510d0a
**
according to the GT06N Documentation here is how to handle lat and long
Latitude:
Four bytes are consumed, defining the latitude value of location data. The range of the value is 0-162000000, indicating a range of 0°-90°. The conversion method thereof is as follow: Converting the value of latitude and longitude output by GPS module into a decimal based on minute; multiplying the converted decimal by 30000; and converting the multiplied result into hexadecimal Example: 22º32.7658‟=(22X60+32.7658)X30000=40582974, then converted into a hexadecimal number 40582974(Decimal)= 26B3F3E(Hexadecimal) at last the value is 0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E
Longitude:
Four bytes are consumed, defining the longitude value of location data. The range of the value is 0-324000000, indicating a range of 0°-180°. The conversion method herein is same to the method mentioned in Latitude (see section 5.2.1.6).
Speed:
One byte is consumed, defining the running Speed of GPS. The value ranges from 0x00 to 0xFF indicating a range from 0 to 225km/h. e.g. 0x00 represents 0 km/h. 0x10 represents 16km/h. 0xFF represents 255km/h
Here is the Link to the documentation am following >> https://github.com/tobadia/petGPS/blob/master/resources/GT06_GPS_Tracker_Communication_Protocol_v1.8.1.pdf
here is my current code with new changes
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import zlib
import os
import binascii


os.environ['TZ'] = 'Africa/Nairobi'

# Function to calculate CRC-ITU (CRC-16-CCITT-FALSE) error check
def crc_itu(data):
    crc = 0xFFFF
    polynomial = 0x1021

    for byte in data:
        crc ^= (byte << 8)

        for _ in range(8):
            if crc & 0x8000:
                crc = ((crc << 1) ^ polynomial) & 0xFFFF
            else:
                crc = (crc << 1) & 0xFFFF

    return crc.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')

# Set timezone to Africa/Nairobi


# Create a TCP server socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((server_ip, server_port))
server.listen(1)

print("Waiting for connection...")

# Accept a client connection
socket, _ = server.accept()

print("Connection established.")

# Receive data from the client
encoded_data = socket.recv(1500)
TrackerData = binascii.hexlify(encoded_data).decode()

print("Received: ", TrackerData)


def extract_packet_info(packet):
    # Start Bit
    start_bit = packet[:4]

    # Packet Length
    packet_length = packet[4:6]

    # Protocol Number
    protocol_number = packet[6:8]

    # Terminal ID
    terminal_id = packet[8:24]

    # Information Serial Number
    info_serial_number = packet[24:28]

    # Error Check
    error_check = packet[28:32]

    # Stop Bit
    stop_bit = packet[32:]

    crc_data = packet[4:28]  # Packet Length to Information Serial Number (inclusive)
    server_error_check = crc_itu(binascii.unhexlify(crc_data))
    print("Server Error Calc", server_error_check)

    reply_packet = f"7878{packet_length}{protocol_number}{info_serial_number}{server_error_check}0d0a"
    server_response_packet = binascii.unhexlify(reply_packet)

    print("Server Reply: ", reply_packet)

    socket.sendall(server_response_packet)

    return {
        "Start Bit": start_bit,
        "Packet Length": packet_length,
        "Protocol Number": protocol_number,
        "Terminal ID": terminal_id,
        "Information Serial Number": info_serial_number,
        "Error Check": error_check,
        "Stop Bit": stop_bit
    }


# Example packet
packet = "78780d01086578405499767400054d5f0d0a"

# Extract information from the packet
packet_info = extract_packet_info(TrackerData)

# Display extracted information
for key, value in packet_info.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")


# Close the connection
socket.close()
server.close()


The packet you decoded wasn't a location packet, so of course you got utter garbage when you tried to interpret it as a location packet.  Notice the Protocol Number of 0x01; that indicates a "Login Message", an actual "Location Data" would be protocol 0x12.

Hi @jasonharper, thanks for replying. this means my reply to the device is not either properly formatted or its incorrect, i guess!!! any help please !
again thankyou in advance

I would assume that you just need to keep receiving packets in a loop, and ignore (or otherwise specially handle) any that aren't Location Data packets.

I have to first successfully respond to the login packet so that device can start sending me Location packets, i have successfully Contracted the reply packet from the server but the issue now is with the CRC-ITU Calculation.
According to the Documentation( See Next 2 Comments )

"  4.6. Error Check
A check code may be used by the terminal or the server to distinguish whether the received
information is error or not. To prevent errors occur during data transmission, error check is added to
against data misoperation, so as to increase the security and efficiency of the system. The check code is generated by the CRC-ITU checking method.
The check codes of data in the structure of the protocol"

from the Packet Length to the Information
Serial Number (including “Packet Length” and “Information Serial Number”) , are values of
CRC-ITU.
CRC error occur when the received information is calculated, the receiver will ignore and discard the
data packet.

check original question and see the new code with the changes
